# Debug ldapmodify schema addition

Tags: docker, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

I am attempting to add an `objectGUID` attribute to an existing LDAP database. I apply the following ldifs:

```
dn: cn={3}inetorgperson,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.1.34234234
  NAME 'objectGUID'
  DESC 'text here'
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.44 )
```

and:

```
dn: cn={3}inetorgperson,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.2.2 NAME 'inetOrgPerson' DESC 'RF
 C2798: Internet Organizational Person' SUP organizationalPerson STRUCTURAL
 MAY ( audio $ businessCategory $ carLicense $ departmentNumber $ displayNam
 e $ employeeNumber $ employeeType $ givenName $ homePhone $ homePostalAddre
 ss $ initials $ jpegPhoto $ labeledURI $ mail $ manager $ mobile $ o $ page
 r $ photo $ roomNumber $ secretary $ uid $ userCertificate $ x500uniqueIden
 tifier $ preferredLanguage $ userSMIMECertificate $ userPKCS12 ) )
-
add: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: {0}( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.2.2 NAME 'inetOrgPerson' DESC 'RF
 C2798: Internet Organizational Person' SUP organizationalPerson STRUCTURAL
 MAY ( audio $ businessCategory $ carLicense $ departmentNumber $ displayNam
 e $ employeeNumber $ employeeType $ givenName $ homePhone $ homePostalAddre
 ss $ initials $ jpegPhoto $ labeledURI $ mail $ manager $ mobile $ o $ page
 r $ photo $ roomNumber $ secretary $ uid $ userCertificate $ x500uniqueIden
 tifier $ preferredLanguage $ userSMIMECertificate $ userPKCS12 $ objectGUID) )
```

Both seem to apply successfully. From phpLDAPAdmin, I cannot see the changes. I am using an openLDAP server. Is there some LDAP technique that I might be missing? Sorry for the basic question, a bit of an LDAP beginner here...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! For posterity, it makes sense to purge caches in phpLDAPAdmin first.

Comment: Bob, thank you for sharing your experience! I assume, you extending scheme for osixia/openldap:1.5.0 docker image? I came to same code (I need objectGUID in my scheme too), mount it to `/container/service/slapd/assets/config/bootstrap/ldif/custom`, but getting error `ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)`. What did you do to make it work?